# Can end-to-end tests in Visual Studio Team Services Build be run?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, azure-devops, end-to-end

I have a set of mocha tests that launch Spectron to do end-to-end testing on an Electron application.

When I try to run the tests through `npm run`, they just time out and fail. It seems that the application isn't launching. There is a `Run Functional Tests` build step template in VSTS, but that's for an actual test DLL. Is there something similar for Javascript end-to-end testing?

Comment: Do you know if the Spectron framework requires you to run on the desktop to run those tests?  If you are running on the Hosted Build Pool you are running as a service not in a Desktop session.

Comment: The test needs to interact with window and run on build agent machine, so the build agent need to run in interactive mode, in other words you need to setup a build agent to run in interactive mode. (Hosted agent is running in service mode) Does your build agent run in interactive mode?

Comment: You need to configure your own build agent and run it in interactive mode as starain mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hosted Agent is running as the service, however launch Spectron to do test with Electron app need to interact with window and the test is running on build agent machine. So you need to setup a on premise build agent to do that test (works fine for me with [this](https://github.com/electron/spectron) test sample. Build steps: npm install, npm install test)

1. Log on to the machine using the account for which you've prepared permissions as explained above.
2. Go to the Agent pools control panel tab
3. Click Download agent.
4. Click Windows.
5. Click the Download button.
6. Run PowerShell as Administrator.
7. Run the commands under Create the agent.
8. Run .\config cmd

More information to setup on premise build agent, you can refer to [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/v2-windows) article.

Comment: Using an on-prem build agent is not the best solution. They should use the Functional Testing task instead.

Comment: @MrHinsh Run Functional Tests task does not apply to Jon's scenario since mocha and spectron run the test base on Node.JS & browser. VS Test agent cannot run this testing.

Comment: I was able to get the steps going. I have the agent locally and can verify that the build runs on it. However, the tests still don't seem to be running even on my local machine as the build agent. Is there something else I may be missing?

Comment: Disregard my previous comment...I was running it as a service instead of interactive mode. It now works! Is there any reason it doesn't work as a service, though? Having it as part of a CI would require the agent to always be running interactively. Probably not a huge deal, but just curious.

Comment: @Jon Because aunch Spectron to do test with Electron app need to interact with window, so agent need to be running interactively. CI build doesn't request build agent running interactively.

Comment: If you are running tests that need desktop interaction then you should be using Functional Testing and Machine Groups. It is neither a good idea, nor a good practice to do that during a compilation process.

Comment: @MrHinsh yes, but not all of test framework could be run in Functional Testing.

Comment: @starain-mart, incorrect: ALL test frameworks can be run through functional testing. All you need is a Visual Studio Test Adapter that supports it. If one has not already been built for that framework then it is easy to create your own. See http://mortenhoustonludvigsen.github.io/JsTestAdapter/CreatingATestAdapter/

Answer (score 0):

Since the tests need to interact with the desktop they are not a good fit for compile time where you dont usually have a running instance of your application. Stick to pure unit tests at build time. A better fit would be to use Release Management to orchastrate those tests.

That said, you can easily deploy your application (build or release) and the. Use the Functional Testing task to initiate your UI interactive tasks. You need a machine with the Test Agent deployed, but there is a task for that too.

[image]

Since Functional (end to end) tests interact with the desktop you can only run one at once. This is fine if you only take a few minutes, but as you get more functional teats this can take way longer. The Functional Testing task allows you to split the test execution across multiple agents so that you can run the tests in parallel.

Since your alternative is to configure your own Build Agent in interactive mode you need a server anyway. You would be more future proofing to use this model from the start as you can scale.

If a Visual Studio Test Adapter is not available for your framework then you can create your own to let Visual Studio, and additionally the Functional Testing plugin, detect and execute any test framework. For Javascript you will find http://mortenhoustonludvigsen.github.io/JsTestAdapter/CreatingATestAdapter/ has some awesome examples of how to create a Jasmin Test Adapter as an example.

Comment: Could you tell me how to run Spectron test via run functional test?

Comment: The Functional template there still requires a DLL name for it to run. Is there a way around that.

Comment: Functional Testing uses the same Test Adapters as the rest of the Visual Studio platform. You need to "install" the Spectron test adapter on the Test Agent. If the "Unit Test" task can run it, the Functional Testing task can too.

Comment: A Test Adapter is required to use both the Visual Studio Unit Test task and the Functional Test task. The Test Adapter will create the bits that you need to run it. If there is not a Test Adapter for Spectron you can find documentation online to make one.

Comment: A good example of Javascript testing is the Jasmin Test Adapter.